# Uninstall Pre-installed Norton Internet Security, And Enable Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-8, uninstall, windows-defender, norton-internet-security

I recently purchased a Windows 8 computer, and Norton Internet Security came preloaded as a trial-ware. Now that the trial is finished, I want to enable Windows defender, and delete Norton Internet Security. Unfortunately, I can't seem to do this.

Comment: Since you do not provide enough info, we can only assume that you haven't tried much nor researched, if this is wrong please update your post with what you tried. Otherwise, a simple [search](http://google.com) appears to yield your desired [result in the form of a how-to](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2020260/how-to-activate-windows-defender-in-windows-8.html)

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE:* It's always best to uninstall one security software before installing/activating another.

## Remove Nortons

Open the control panel and click "Uninstall a Program".

[image: Insert screenshot 7]

Find Nortons in the list and select it.  Then click "Uninstall/Change".

[image: insert screenshot 9]
NOTE:  The screenshot doesn't show Nortons because I don't have it installed.  It will normally be called something like "Norton Internet Security".

## Activate Windows Defender

Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> and type "Windows Defender". Make sure you're searching under "Apps" in the right panel.

[image: insert screenshot 4]

Open Windows Defender.  Switch to the "Settings" tab and select "Administrator" from the left pane.  Check the checkbox titled "Turn on Windows Defender".

[image: insert screenshot 6]

Click "Save Changes".

**If you don't have any other security software installed and Windows Defender is off you can do it this was too:**

Open the Control Panel and Navigate to `System and Security -> Action Center`.  You should see several warnings about Windows Defender.  Click "Turn on Now"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is necessary to set the value `DisableAntiSpyware` to `0` under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows Defender` in the Registry.

Note, you must take ownership of this key and give your user account full control over this key.